# web api где выполняются?

Tags: javascript

Js является однопоточным языком, где выполняются web api, их выполнение происходит в браузере отдельно от js?

Можно ли это назвать много поточностью получается и js код выполняется и ещё в браузере какой, то код работает?

Например функция

```
setTimeout("alert('Привет')", 10000)
```

- Где происходит счёт времени?
- В потоки js или в потоке браузера и потом браузер сообщает js, что счёт закончен?

https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ?t=835

Comment: Что конкретно вы имеете в виду под термином «web api»?

Comment: За многопоточность javascript обычно отвечает [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv).

Comment: имею в виду где выполняют вот эти функции https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API

Comment: Где вы сами захотите их запустить, там они и выполнятся. Если на странице сайта — то на странице сайта в однопоточном режиме. Если в сервис-воркере — то в отдельном процессе сервис-воркера. Если для nodejs установите какую-нибудь эмуляцию этих API — то в nodejs.

Comment: К setTimeout это тоже относится, он запускается там, где вы сами его запускаете, и он не создаёт и не использует никаких дополнительных потоков. Если вы запустите alert через setTimeout на странице, то эта страница всё равно зависнет, потому что alert заблокирует её до тех пор, пока пользователь не нажмёт OK

Comment: Чуть более конкретно, в js-движке есть цикл событий (event loop), который ждёт наступления каких-нибудь событий (например, нажатие кнопки или получение ответа на ajax-запрос) и обрабатывает их по мере их поступления. Функция setTimeout просто создаёт ещё одно событие, срабатывающее через указанное количество времени, и event loop обрабатывает это событие как обычно. Всё это происходит в одном потоке (в том, в котором вы запустили setTimeout). Подробнее об этом можно почитать тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: js сам по себе принципиально однопоточный и работать в нескольких потоках не умеет. В ситуациях, когда хочется иметь реальную многопоточность, запускают несколько отдельных экземпляров js-движка, которые друг с другом никак не связаны (не могут читать и изменять объекты друг друга), а могут только обмениваться сообщениями. В браузерах такими отдельными экземплярами являются например сервис-воркеры, в nodejs это worker threads

Comment: а сама функция setTimeout она же где, то срабатывает? то есть отчёт идёт сработай через 10 секунд и туда, как приходит ответ?  web api разве он не в браузере отдельно работает? вот тут сказано по другому не уверен конечно, что правильно https://coderoad.ru/49264524/%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80-web-api-%D0%B2-Javascript

Comment: тут по другому рассказывается https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ?t=744

Comment: Подозреваю, что здесь нет однозначного ответа и надо смотреть конкретные реализации в конкретных браузерах/средах. К сожалению, лично я недостаточно компетентен для этого

Comment: В любом случае, отсчётом времени занимается операционная система, так как простые программы не имеют прямого доступа к аппаратным часам компьютера. То есть реально выполняемый отсчёт 10 секунд идёт не в js-движке и даже не в браузере, а где-то в глубинах операционной системы, которая ожидает получения прерывания от аппаратных часов